# How to display Fullscreen image from RecyclerView in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, imageview, adapter

i am getting data from API and display it in RecyclerView and everything is working fine

but now i'm a bit confused on how can i display the images that i'm getting from the API in full screen if the user clicked on it

this is the activity:

LlmNoteDetailsActivity:

```
class LlmNoteDetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_ilm_note_detail)


    val EventName = intent.getStringExtra("EventName")
    val EventLink = intent.getStringExtra("EventLink")
    val isFavourite = intent.getBooleanExtra("isFavourite" , false)
    val eventId = intent.getIntExtra("eventId",0)
    val eventDate = intent.getStringExtra("eventDate")
    val eventDescription = intent.getStringExtra("eventDescription")
    val eventLocation = intent.getStringExtra("eventLocation")
    val eventLink = intent.getStringExtra("eventLink")
    val EventImage = intent.getStringExtra("EventImage")


    val ImageViewTop: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.ImageViewTop)
    val LinkText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.LocationTx)
    val EventNameText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.EventNameText)
    val eventDateTxt: TextView = findViewById(R.id.eventDateTxt)
    val eventDescriptionText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.eventDescriptionText)
    val butttoRegiiste: Button = findViewById(R.id.butttoRegiiste)
    val detailback_btn: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.detailback_btn)


    LinkText.text = EventLink
    EventNameText.text = EventName
    eventDateTxt.text = eventDate
    eventDescriptionText.text = eventDescription

    butttoRegiiste.setOnClickListener {

        openLinkInBrowser(eventLink!!)
    }

    detailback_btn.setOnClickListener {

        onBackPressed()
    }

    ImageViewTop.setOnClickListener {
        //display image in fullscreen
    }


    Picasso.get()
        .load(EventImage)
        .error(R.drawable.qiblacompass)
        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
        .into(ImageViewTop)






}



fun openLinkInBrowser(url: String) {


    try {
        val url = if (Uri.parse(url).scheme == null || !url.startsWith("https://") && !url.startsWith(
                "http://"
            )) {
            "https://$url"
        } else url
        val webPage: Uri = Uri.parse(url)

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webPage)

        this.startActivity(intent)


    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
}
```

this its layout(fragment_ilm_note_detail):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
            android:id="@+id/ImageViewTop"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="login background"
            android:src="@drawable/sampledetail" />





        <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:flexDirection="column">
            <LinearLayout
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_16"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_16"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_16"
                android:elevation="5dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="20dp">

                    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        app:justifyContent="space_between"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
                            app:alignItems="center"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/pin"
                                android:layout_width="18dp"
                                android:layout_height="25dp"/>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/LocationTx"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                                android:text="Ara Damansara"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />
                        </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/star"
                            android:layout_width="25dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"/>
                    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/EventNameText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                        android:text="Perfecting My Solah"
                        android:textColor="@color/teal_600"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/eventDateTxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                        android:text="Sabtu 15 Ogos 2021"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/eventDescriptionText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/butttoRegiiste"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/dimen_32"
                        android:backgroundTint="#FFB248"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:text="Link to Register"
                        app:rippleColor="#FFB248" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/detailback_btn"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/chevron_left" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

this is the adapter:

IimfinderAdapter:

```
class IimfinderAdapter(var countryList: List<ilmFinders>, private val iimfinderAdapterCallback: MainActivity): RecyclerView.Adapter<IimfinderAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
lateinit var context: Context
val CategoryID: Int = AppPreferences.heightInCentimeters ?: 170
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): IimfinderAdapter.ViewHolder {
    context = parent.context!!
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item2, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: IimfinderAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    var categoryIDis = countryList[CategoryID].categoryID

    Log.e("CategoryID",categoryIDis.toString())
    Log.e("Categorycount ",countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders.size.toString())




    holder.eventName.text = countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders[position].eventName
    holder.eventLink.text = countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders[position].eventLink
    Log.d("ggggggggggggggg", countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders[position].eventName)



   var ilmfinderimage =  countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders[position].eventPhoto.toString()

  var newatri =  ilmfinderimage.replace("[", "").replace("" +
          "]", "")
    Log.d("ffffffffff", newatri)





    Picasso.get()
        .load(newatri)
        .error(R.drawable.qiblacompass)
        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
        .into(holder.eventPhoto)




    holder.list_card.setOnClickListener {

        countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders[position].eventName
        countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders[position].eventLink
        newatri

        //context.startActivity(Intent(context, LlmNoteDetailsActivity::class.java))

        var intent = Intent(context, LlmNoteDetailsActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("EventName",countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders[position].eventName)
        intent.putExtra("EventLink",countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders[position].eventLink)
        intent.putExtra("isFavourite",countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders[position].isFavourite)
        intent.putExtra("eventId",countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders[position].eventId)
        intent.putExtra("eventDate",countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders[position].eventDate)
        intent.putExtra("eventDescription",countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders[position].eventDescription)
        intent.putExtra("eventLocation",countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders[position].eventLocation)
        intent.putExtra("eventLink",countryList[CategoryID].ilmFinders[position].eventLink)
        intent.putExtra("EventImage",newatri)
        context.startActivity(intent)

    }

}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val eventName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_tv2)
    val eventLink: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_url2)
    val eventPhoto: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_tv2)
    val list_card: ConstraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_constraint)


}
```

}

and this is its layout(list_item2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.bigman.wmzx.customcardview.library.CardView
android:id="@+id/list_card"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="250dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
app:contentPadding="8dp">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_constraint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail_tv2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/insta"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_tv2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:textColor="#4B4B4B"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/thumbnail_tv2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_url2"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/linkiimfinder"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_tv2"
         />




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.bigman.wmzx.customcardview.library.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

so in (fragment_ilm_note_detail) layout there is an ImageView (id:ImageViewTop) i'm trying to display this image in full screen if the user click on it

i tried to create new activity and layout to show only the image and i added setOnClickListener if the user click the image but i faced few errors

what is the easiest way to achieve this?

"please be patient with me becasue i'm new to Kotlin"

i have been searching online for almost 3 days for this problem and i couldn't find the right solution for my case that's why i'm asking here, please relate to my code if you have a solution

Answer (score 0):

You don't create a new activity inside `holder.list_card.setOnClickListener`. Instead, create a new fragment, with it's own xml layout with fullScreen imageView. For example, the kotlin code for fragment:

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class FullScreenImageFragment: Fragment() {

    companion object {
        val TAG: String =  "FullScreenImageFragment"
        val INPUT_IMAGE: String = "INPUT_IMAGE"

        fun getInstance(inputImageUrl: String): FullScreenImageFragment {
            val fullScreenImageFragment = FullScreenImageFragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putString(INPUT_IMAGE, inputImageUrl)
            fullScreenImageFragment.arguments = args
            return fullScreenImageFragment
        }
    }

    private var inputImageUrl: String = ""
    private lateinit var fragmentRootView: View

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        this.fragmentRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.full_screen_image, container, false)
        this.fragmentRootView.setOnClickListener { /* empty listener to prevent click propagation */ }
        return fragmentRootView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initArgument()

        val imagePreview: ImageView = fragmentRootView.findViewById(R.id.imagePreview)
        Picasso.get()
            .load(inputImageUrl)
            .error(R.drawable.qiblacompass)
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .into(imagePreview)
    }

    private fun initArgument() {
        if(arguments!=null) {
            this.inputImageUrl = requireArguments().getString(INPUT_IMAGE, "")
        }
    }
}
```

The xml layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And finally, inside your adapter:

```
holder.list_card.setOnClickListener{
  val activity: Activity = holder.context as Activity
activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, FullScreenImageFragment.getInstance(newatri))  // "www.some_image_url.com"
                .commit()
}
```

This should do the work. Consider studying some more on fragments to further modify the code.

Comment: i understand now for the layout and the fragment but what i need to add in the adapter i didn't get it and didn't work, should i replace "holder.context as Activity" with "eventPhoto" for context? or not? and for "supportFragmentManager" its "Unresolved reference: supportFragmentManager" and also for ".replace(android.R.id.content," what id should i call?

Comment: try ```           val activity:  AppCompatActivity =   itemView.context as AppCompatActivity;
            activity.supportFragmentManager  ``` This should resolve the conflict

Comment: it did solve the problem now left the "itemView" in "val activity: AppCompatActivity = itemView.context as AppCompatActivity" i tried to replace it with with "eventPhoto" but it didn't work

Comment: and also for ".replace(android.R.id.content," what id should i include? the image id?

Comment: try `val activity: AppCompatActivity = holder.itemView.context as AppCompatActivity` or `val activity: AppCompatActivity = context as AppCompatActivity`, and android.R.id.content is the builtin layout id for mounting fragments. Usually we use a frameLayout and use the frameLayout's id here. Since you don't have a frameLayout, and I don't want to complicate things, I used android.R.layout.content which should work.

Comment: Could you share the project using github / some other means? At this point, I really cannot help without seeing the project.

Comment: its big project, do you need any code other than the ones i provided?

Comment: Your given code is ok, and I tried to solve it with your given code, but your code is crashing. So I need to run the code and see where it is crashing. I really don't know what went wrong.

Comment: i solved it and posted it my answer, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

so what i did here:

i created new Activity with its layout:

Activity:

```
    val detailback_btn: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.detailback_btn2)
    val EventImage = intent.getStringExtra("EventImage")
    val thumbnail_tv22: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_tv22)

    Picasso.get()
        .load(EventImage)
        .error(R.drawable.qiblacompass)
        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
        .into(thumbnail_tv22)

    detailback_btn.setOnClickListener {

        onBackPressed()
    }
   }
```

i passed the image "val EventImage = intent.getStringExtra("EventImage")"

and from "LlmNoteDetailsActivity" i added setOnClickListener to open new Activity and passed the image:

LlmNoteDetailsActivity:

```
   ImageViewTop.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivityV2::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("EventImage",EventImage)
        startActivity(intent)
     }
```